# React компонент не получает функцию mutate в props через graphql HOC

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql

Мне необходимо пробросить мутацию в компонент. При использовании данной строки кода:

```
export default graphql(logOn)(Login)
```

ничего не происходит. Нет никаких ошибок, просто компонент не получает функцию mutate в props.

Однако, если я перепишу код следующим образом:

```
const logOnWithMutation = graphql(logOn)(Login);
export default logOnWithMutation;
```

и сошлюсь на него в родительском компоненте:

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
      <Fragment>
        <logOnWithMutation/>
      </Fragment>
    </ApolloProvider>
  )
}
```

то все прекрасно работает. Функция mutate приходит в props компонента Login

Что я упускаю? Мне необходимо, чтобы вариант `export default graphql(logOn)(Login)` работал.

Comment: А как вы импортируете `logOnWithMutation` в родительском компоненте, когда пишете `export default graphql(logOn)(Login)` ?

Comment: @Denis Bubnov  В первом случае я вообще не создаю переменную `logOnWithMutation`. У меня есть компонент Login (он импортируется в родительский компонент по имени), далее, при строке `export default graphql(logOn)(Login)` компонент должен оборачиватся graphql HOC и получать мутацию logOn в props. Мне необходимо, чтобы именно этот вариант был рабочим.

Comment: Есть подозрения, что где-то неправильно происходит `import\export`, от этого и проблема. Там где у вас лежит компонент `Login` есть индексный файл с экспортами или нет? Если да. то я бы предложил написать там такой экспорт: `export { default as Login } from './Login';` а потом импортить компонент где нужно вот так: `import { Login } from 'путь индесному файлу';`

Comment: @Denis Bubnov, спасибо, навели на правильные мысли!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение:

чтобы работал данный вариант `export default graphql(logOn)(Login)` и данном экспорте компонента `export class Login extends Component`, в родительском компоненте необходимо импортировать компонент Login следующим образом `import Login from './containers/login/login';`. Я же делал импорт по имени, т.е. `import { Login } from './containers/login/login';`